# F#: error creating a list of size n

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm trying to create a list of size n pulling elements from a larger, already created list.
I'm getting an error saying:
This value is not a function and cannot be applied.
Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s). at 7,16

Can anyone help see what I'm doing wrong? Also, I'm trying to understand F# so I don't really want anything that can do what I'm asking for me, unless it's an FYI kind of thing. But I'd still want help creating a function to do this.

```
//create a list of size n from beginning of a dataset
let populateList n =
    let starterList = []
    let data = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]
    let rec helper count aList = 
        let head::tail = aList
        if count < k then head :: helper count+1 tail else []


    helper 0 data

populateList 3
```

Comment: Can you show what is the expected output given your input?

Comment: Expected output should be [1;2;3]

Comment: `List.take 3 data`, you could explore what that function does.

Comment: Ok, but I'm also trying to write a function that'll do this without that built in functionality b/c I'm still learning functional programming

Comment: It would help if you told us which line it's complaining about

Comment: I'm not really sure, F# interactive says "8,51" for the first error where "This value is not a function and cannot be applied" but that line is empty. I think it's the line with "let head::tail" b/c I'm not completely sure if that's legal? Otherwise I'm thinking it's the line right below wiht the if else?

Comment: you should look into pattern matching.

Comment: I know about pattern matching, but I don't know how to do pattern matching when I'm only trying to do something n times, rather than until the end of a list

Comment: @JLRishe has the right answer: you're running into operator precedence. Function calls bind more tightly than operators, so you can do something like `firstFunction firstParam + secondFunction secondParam` and get what you'd probably expect: the result of those two function calls will be added together. In your case, though, you need the parentheses around `(count+1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's failing to run because of this:

```
head :: helper count+1 tail
```

Because function invocations have higher operator precedence than the infix `+` operator, this is being interpreted as:

```
head :: ((helper count) + (1 tail))
```

Since `1` is not a function, you are getting an error here.

You can fix this by adding parentheses:

```
head :: helper (count+1) tail
```

---

The "Incomplete pattern matches" warning will not prevent it from running, but it does indicate something that you should address because it can lead to a runtime error.

The correct way to address it is by using pattern matching to cover all the possible patterns:

```
let rec helper count aList = 
    match aList with
    | head::tail -> if count < n then head :: helper (count+1) tail else []
    | [] -> []
```

This will ensure that you do not attempt to split an empty list into a head and a tail.

Since this function now returns `[]` both in the base case and in the case that `aList` is empty, you can further simplify this by using `when` and a default match condition:

```
let rec helper count aList = 
    match aList with
    | head::tail when count < n -> head :: helper (count+1) tail
    | _ -> []
```